# Adding a href link to a checkbox once selected

Tags: javascript, html

So I currently have coded in HTML when a user clicks "Customize" a modal pops up with checkboxes. Once a checkbox is selected and the user clicks "Submit", what the user selected will show up on the page and the modal will vanish. What I'm trying to do is, have the selected content turn into a link (href) once selected. I've got it to where it makes the checkbox content a link in the modal but I don't want it there, I want it to convert into a link once it's been selected and the user clicks submit. The following is the code I currently have in HTML and JS

```js
$('#youtube').change(function() {
  var chb = document.getElementsByClassName('chkbx');

  if (chb[0].checked) {
    console.log("YOUTUBE selected");
    $(this).next().html("<a href='https://www.youtube.com/'>YOUTUBE</a>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <div class="title">Please select preferred websites: </div>
    <button data-submit-button class="submit-button" onclick="getValue()">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" id="youtube" name="website" value="youtube"> YOUTUBE <br>
```

Comment: You can NEVER use document.write after the page has loaded. add it to the html:                 `$(this).next().html("YOUTUBE selected <a href='https://www.youtube.com/'>YOUTUBE</a>")`

Answer (score 0):

You can only use next if you have something next

Otherwise use .after() or parent().append()

```js
$('#youtube').on("click",function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("YOUTUBE selected");
    $(this).parent().next().html("<a href='https://www.youtube.com/'>YOUTUBE</a>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <div class="title">Please select preferred websites: </div>
    <button type="button" data-submit-button class="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" id="youtube" name="website" value="youtube"> YOUTUBE </label>
    <span>This is the next</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use replaceWith if you want the checkbox to become a link

Here when submit is clicked

```js
$('.submit-button').on("click",function() {
  const $check = $("#youtube")
  if ($check.is(":checked")) {
    console.log("YOUTUBE selected");
    $check.parent().replaceWith("<a href='https://www.youtube.com/'>YOUTUBE</a>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <div class="title">Please select preferred websites: </div>
    <button type="button" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" id="youtube" name="website" value="youtube"> YOUTUBE</label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I changed the JS code to what you had above and added the script line above the        <div class="modal active" id="modal"> and it still doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful description. The code I posted works as far as I could guess what you need. As you can see, the checkbox is replaced by the link

Comment: When I select the checkbox and click the submit button, it still doesn't edit the YOUTUBE to a hyperlink.

Comment: I do it onclick of the checkbox. I can do it on click of the submit if you want

Comment: See second example now

Comment: Yeah I don't even think mine is executing that function because nothing is happening correctly. But the updated code is the correct functionality I was looking for. Thanks!!!